# Socialauth fb access token after login

Tags: java, django-socialauth, socialauth

I have logged in to facebook from my server app and I can get my profile information and contacts etc.

However how can I use this to get the accesstoken that I could use for restfb? Or is there way in socialauth that I can execute FQL, or read the users events list?

```
List<Contact> contactsList = new ArrayList<>();
    SocialAuthManager manager = socialAuthTemplate.getSocialAuthManager();
    AuthProvider provider = manager.getCurrentAuthProvider();

    contactsList = provider.getContactList();
```

Current method of getting the contact list.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try to use [Facebook 4j](http://facebook4j.org/en/code-examples.html)

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

```
   String query = "SELECT src_big "
                            + "FROM photo "
                            + "WHERE aid IN "
                            + "(SELECT aid "
                                + "FROM album "
                                + "WHERE name = " + "\"" + albumname + "\" AND owner IN "
                                    + "(SELECT uid "
                                    + "FROM user "
                                    + "WHERE username = " + "\"" + username + "\"))";

// Single FQL
mPhotos = facebook.executeFQL(query);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the access token by AccessGrant Object

```
String token = provider.getAccessGrant().getKey();
```

Or if you want to make any REST call then you can use the API method

```
public Response api(String url, final String methodType,
            final Map<String, String> params,
            final Map<String, String> headerParams, final String body)
            throws Exception;
```

Here you can pass the REST URL and other parameter values or null for that.